# Why the value structure is different when debugging?

Tags: kotlin

**My environment:**

- JDK 1.8
- IDEA Ultimate 2017.2.5
- Kotlin plugin 1.1.51-release-IJ2017.2-1

**I have a function which is simple:**

```
fun generateValue(param:KParameter):Any? {
    // do something here
}
```

**The problem is** 
When I debug this function, let's say put a breakpoint in its body. And look into the value of `param`.

It has a completely different structure than the `KParameter` interface.

The `KParameter` is:

```
public interface KParameter : KAnnotatedElement {
    public val index: Int
    public val name: String?
    public val type: KType
    public val kind: Kind
    public enum class Kind {
        INSTANCE,
        EXTENSION_RECEIVER,
        VALUE,
    }
    public val isOptional: Boolean

    @SinceKotlin("1.1")
    public val isVararg: Boolean
}
```

And the real value, at least from debugger is an object which type is [KParameterImpl](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/KParameterImpl.kt), I think it's the actual implementation of that interface?

But what makes it worse:

1. You can't access its members in the debugger via `expression evaluation` since it's not included in the
   interface. For instance, even you see there is a property A with value `1` in the debugger, but you can't access it in the debugger via typing `param.A`
2. You can't see the properties from the `KParameter` interface as well,
   such as: `name`, `type`, etc.

This results in a very confusing development cycle.

**My question is:**
Is this a bug? or an intentional design or I did something wrong?

Comment: The debugger does not show Kotlin properties but instead shows the fields of the instance. The properties of the interface are most likely implemented with custom getters and do not have backing fields of their own. To inspect the properties, you can [evaluate them as expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html) or add watches. (But note: there's an issue with the debugger: if there are Kotlin property and a field with the same names, it will choose the latter. The workaround for such cases is to call the getter as a method).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I know you could use `expression` like `param.name` to access it, what confuses me is that this implicit is a little annoying. :)